# Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

I keep on getting this error:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: XXX)

I am using mamp server to run my web server. why do i get this error? everything looks fine to me but it denys me access.

here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbtechnerdzzz";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (empty($_POST['form-username']) || empty($_POST['form-password'])) {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
  }
  else
  {
    $connection=mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['form-username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['form-password']);
    // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from accounts where Password='$password' AND Username='$username'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows == 1) {
      $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
      header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To profile Page
    } else {
      $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    header("location: signin.php"); // Redirecting To login Page
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you login using this user name and password in localhost mysql data base?

Comment: Go to phpmyadmin, under users and check if root is assigned to the host localhost.

Comment: there is error in your user  details.

Comment: I thought the default password for the root user was root in mamp, as i see from your code you have set it to empty...

Comment: check using this function where you get error mysqli_connect_errno()

Comment: @PruthvirajChudasama Check what??

Comment: You are not setting a password, so therefore we must assume that there is a password set on the `root@localhost` MYSQL account. What did you set it to? The default is `root` so try that

Answer (score 3):

mamp's Default password is **root**. 
Change your configuration like this.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbtechnerdzzz";
$user = "root";
$password = "root";
```